# Preferred order of declarations and #defines in a header file

Tags: c, linux, coding-style, macros, header-files

I am programing in C language in Linux platform . I want to know should be the order of declarations and `#defines` in a header file.

For example if my header file includes following thing can anyone please suggest me what should the perfect order to arrange all these declarations, function like macros , exteren declarations, etc.

This can be really beneficial for arranging all these things in a header file properly in terms of readability and coding standards.

Below is the sample header file (I want to arrange the following in a proper order)  :

```
 #include <pthread.h>                   //  Including Header files 
 #include <signal.h>

 #define IMAGE_DIRECTORY                 "Abcdefgh..."   //  Providing #defines 
 #define FAILED_TO_RECOGNIZE             "Xykbkksk..."
 #define PROGRESS_FRAME_COLOR            "#8e8ea1"
 #define FRAME_BG_COLOR                  "#7c90ac"      

 #define PRINT_FUNCTION_NAME fprintf(stderr, 
                   "CTRL IN FUNCTION : %s\n",__func__);   // Macro like functions 
typedef struct {                                           
        int userId;                                      // Structure
         char name[32], rollNo[32];
         char class[16], section[16];
         unsigned long Id;
 }data_type;

int noOfUsersList=0, usersListCount=0;                   // Global variables
```

Comment: I suggest you to look *inside* `/usr/include/pthread.h` to see how it is done.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't done this for years but when I was heavily developing for Unix, MS.DOS, OS/2, NetWare, and Windows simultaneously I developed this practice:

1. Language #includes
2. Operating system #includes
3. #includes from other subsystems, e.g. X11.
4. My own application #includes.
5. My own local #defines for this source file.
6. My own forward declarations for this file.

Maybe you can reverse (1) and (2) but I found this order to work the best across quite  a number of compilers and operating systems.

Answer (score 3):

Coding style is subjective, personally I use the rules and methods described below, but please note that are my own opinions and no absolute truths. Yet they are based on long experience and in some cases on widely-recognized coding standards (MISRA, CERT etc).

Rules:

- C programming is done in "code modules", where every module consists of a .h file and a .c file.
- #includes shall always be in the .h file and never in the .h file, since the .h file should be regarded as public. You want the person that is going to use your module to know what dependencies there are.
- There is never a reason to use non-const global variables in C, so where to place non-const globals and externs isn't relevant to me.
- .h files shouldn't contain any definitions. This is not only bad program design, it is also an excellent way to conjure numerous hard-to-solve linker errors.

In a .h file, the following items are allowed to appear, in the stated order:

- Start of header guard. (`#ifndef MYHEADER_H` ...)
- Library #includes.
- Other #includes.
- Impl.-specific compiler settings such as compiler options set with #pragmas.
- Public numeric constants as #defines.
- Public macros.
- Public type definitions, including opaque types.
- Declaration of public constants (declared as `extern const`).
- Inline function definitions (rare special case, avoid if possible).
- Function prototypes.
- End of header guard. `#endif`

In a .c file, the following items are allowed to appear, in the stated order:

- Include of its own corresponding .h file.
- Private numeric constants in #defines.
- Private macros.
- Definition of opaque types, that were declared as incomplete type in the corresponding .h file.
- Private type definitions.
- Definition of public constants (declared as `extern const` in the .h file).
- Definition of private constants (`static const`).
- Definition of private variables at file scope (`static`).
- Declaration of private functions (declared as `static type func (type param);`)
- Definition of the public functions declared in the .h file.
- Definition of private functions.

Answer (score 1):

Macro definitions with `#define` are *not* declarations. The only requirement is that macros should be defined before their usage. They stay defined until end of compilation unit, or an explicit `#undef` (or a redefinition...).

My stylistic convention is to define statement-like macros as having a "function" like syntax, something like:

```
 #define PRINT_FUNCTION_NAME() fprintf(stderr, \
     "CTRL IN FUNCTION: %s @%s:%d\n", __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

Notice the empty formal macro argument (ie first `()`) and the lack of terminating semicolon (because you will *use* it as a quasi-function call, e.g. `PRINT_FUNCTION_NAME();` statement). Notice also use of `__FILE__`  and `__LINE__`  in a debug message.

Quite often, a statement-like macro is a `do{` *something* `} while(0)` because this is a syntax which has a statement like look and can *always* be used as a statement (including as the *then* part of an `if`, or in `else` branch, etc...). An example from `<ncurses.h>` :

```
#define getsyx(y,x) do { if (newscr) { \
             if (is_leaveok(newscr)) \
            (y) = (x) = -1; \
             else \
             getyx(newscr,(y), (x)); \
        } \
        } while(0)
```

Comment: pls don't take my words like everything is declaration in a header file ... i meant  to say that there can be some declarations, function like macros etc ...

Comment: hi Basile ... thanks for mentioning valuable points .. but my main concern is the order of all this ...for example we first include header files , then what ... , then what ... like this .

Comment: The *requirement* is that a macro should be `#define`-d (perhaps in some `#include`-d header) before any using occurrence. The rest is coding style or other *conventions*. You could use `gcc -C -E -H` to get the preprocessed form.

Comment: The do-while(0) syntax only fills one purpose: avoiding bugs caused by `if(something) invoke_macro();`. The solution to this is not to adopt a weird macro syntax, but to adopt a coding style where {} are mandatory. As reference, MISRA-C encourages do-while(0) in the current 2004 document, but it has been removed in the new draft since the syntax is pointless if you always use {}.